# How to make centered fixed width body responsive?

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design

I have this very simple CSS layout, which will restrict the body width and center it on the screen:

```
body { max-width: 38em; margin: auto; }
```

I expected this to be perfectly responsive: On huge screens the lines will stay short and the body centered, on small screens the body will take hold of all of the screen it can get. This works in my web browser's "Responsive Design View". But on mobile devices, the page is displayed as if it was a huge screen: Tiny text, big margins on the side. How can I tell mobile browsers to stop behaving this stupid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the viewport width when working with mobile browsers.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Read More: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Comment: Can I set this in CSS somehow? I don't see why my markup should be littered with layout code?

Comment: I just found https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@viewport
It sure sucks that this is not supported and we have the meta tag instead. :(